# Prove that a homomorphism is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, ring-homomorphism, gaussian-integers

Let $R$ be the Gaussian integer and $J = (2 + 3i)Z[i]$ a ideal of R. Let $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R/J$ be a homomorphism defined by $\phi(n) = n + J$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I am having difficult to prove that $\phi$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a+bi+J\in\mathcal R/J$.  Then $\phi (a-5b)=a-5b+J=a+bi+J$.

This is because $a-5b-(a+bi)=(b-bi)(2+3i)$.

Thus $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: How did you find $c$ and $d$ such that $(a - 5b) = (a + bi) + (c + di)(2 + 3i)$? I mean, how did you guess that $c = b$ and $d = -b$?

Comment: I just multiplied through and equated real and imaginary parts.   I used Bezout's identity at one point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:\mathbb{Z}[i]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+3i)$ be the quotient map; $(2+3i)(1-i)=5+i$ implies that $\phi(5-(2+3i)(1-i))=-\phi(5)=p(i)$, since $\phi(1)=p(1)$, we deduce that $\phi$ is surjective.